# Why can't I call custom if-check on product view?

Tags: magento-1.9, module, xml, if

I've got a (custom) module which allows me to add YouTube video's to a product. I call that module in my `local.xml` like such:

```
<block type="mymod_catalog/video" name="video" template="catalog/product/view/video.phtml" />
```

I call the block in my `catalog/product/view.phtml` like so:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('video') ?>
```

And in the included template file `video.phtml` it has a check like this:

```
<?php if($this->getProductVideo()): ?>
```

But if I use that if-check in my `view.phtml` it doesn't work (it's always false). I can't figure out why, though. Can anybody tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: Does video block extend core product block ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because the `getProductVideo` method is defined in the block with the alias `mymod_catalog/video` and inside the template `video.phtml`,  `$this` is an instance of that block.

In `view.phtml`, `$this` is an instance of `Magento_Catalog_Block_Product_View` and calling the method `getProductVideo` that does not exist in this block results in calling `Magento_Catalog_Block_Product_View::getData('product_video')` which I assume will always return `null` because you never call `setProductVideo` on this class instance.

You can try to use this in the `view.phtml`.

```
<?php $videoBlock = $this->getChild('video');?>
<?php if ($videoBlock && $videoBlock->getProductVideo()) : ?>
    <!-- your code here -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Marius, hero! Not only did your code work, your easy explanation also helps me grasp the MVVC model in Magento a bit better! Thanks :D